# I see cookies in storage tab in my browser. But when I console log them I always see undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, vue.js, web-development-server

**I only see cookies storage tab but cannot access them via my code**
When I console.log this token and id it results in "undefined" but in my browser storage cookies are shown

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const express = require('express');

const app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
   
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    function getLinkedinId(req) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me';
          const headers = {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.cookies.token,
              'cache-control': 'no-cache',
              'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0' 
          };
          request.get({url: url, headers: headers}, (err, response, body) => {
              if(err){
                  reject(err);
              }
              resolve(JSON.parse(body).id);
          })
      })
    }
    const id = await getLinkedinId(req);
    res.cookie('id', id)
    console.log(`id: ${req.cookies.id}`)
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/about')
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about `console.log(`id: ${req.cookies.id}`)`? Shouldn't it be `res` instead of `req`? Typo?

Comment: No read documentation of cookie parser

Answer (score 0):

This is because you won't have that cookie coming from the client right after you're setting it. The concept is that you set a cookie on a response, and when the client sends another request it would attach the cookie to that.

In your case the cookie would be available on the subsequent requests, imagine this scenario: Someones logs in, the response will have a cookie attached and on the subsequent call to a private page the cookie gets evaluated:

```js
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  res
    .writeHead(200, {
      "Set-Cookie": "token=encryptedstring; HttpOnly",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    })
    .send();
});

app.get("/private", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.cookies.token) return res.status(401).send();
  res.status(200).json({ secret: "Welcome to the private page" });
});
```